# How can I get a UNIQUE window of the user on a Citrix system?

Tags: c#, winforms, citrix

I am creating an application that will run on Citrix, and the application will run on a machine that multiple users log into.

Here is the scenario:  User A logs in to machine 1.  User B logs in to machine 1  Our program starts up when user A logs in.  User B then opens any program (which we are monitoring) and is supposed to receive a dialog asking a question.  However instead of user B receiving the dialog, user A gets the dialog.

How can I parent / show our dialog to the correct user?

I tried parenting the dialog to the Desktop, thinking each user has their own unique desktop, but that didn't work. (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38926203/does-setting-the-parent-to-the-desktop-mean-the-parent-is-null?noredirect=1#comment65210215_38926203) )

Any suggestions / ideas / or examples would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: _"Our program starts up"_ -- where? _"which we are monitoring"_ -- how? Without a good [mcve], this question is too broad at best. It sounds like you run your monitoring program in one user's session; if you want a window to show in any user's session, you need to run your program in each user's session, and have each process instance monitor only the programs running in that session. Without specifics, it's impossible to say exactly how you'd do that though.

Comment: Peter - how do you get a user's session?  that would be a great starting point !

Comment: _"how do you get a user's session"_ -- that would depend on what you mean by "session". Typically, if you want to run a program in each user's session, you just configure the program as a startup program for each user. You don't need any access to the session state itself per se. The program just runs when the user logs in. If you want something other than that, you need to be more specific, and of course use that specificity when you are doing your research on the topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, on a citrix system (and windows OS), every process is associated with a user SID.  However on a citrix system when I setup a WMI query to watch a particular process, I get the notification for ANY user that interacts with that process.

So my application needs to track not only what process I am interested in, but also the USER that is interacting with that process.

this code figures out who owns the process:  (of course what is missing is the code that detects the process activity and calls 'GetProcessOwnerInformation', but that is left as an exercise for the reader :-) )

```
    private ProcessOwnerInformation GetProcessOwnerInformation(uint processId)
    {
        WindowsIdentity _user = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
        string stringSID = string.Empty;
        string process = ExGetProcessInfoByPID((int)processId, out stringSID);

        bool bIgnoreCase = true;

        ProcessOwnerInformation retval = new ProcessOwnerInformation();
        bool bOwnsProcess = string.Compare(stringSID, _user.User.Value, bIgnoreCase) == 0;
        if(bOwnsProcess)
        {
            retval.procID = processId;
            retval.OwnsProcess = bOwnsProcess;
            retval.SID = stringSID;
        }

        return retval;
    }


    public const int TOKEN_QUERY = 0X00000008;

    const int ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS = 259;

    enum TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS
    {
        TokenUser = 1,
        TokenGroups,
        TokenPrivileges,
        TokenOwner,
        TokenPrimaryGroup,
        TokenDefaultDacl,
        TokenSource,
        TokenType,
        TokenImpersonationLevel,
        TokenStatistics,
        TokenRestrictedSids,
        TokenSessionId
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct TOKEN_USER
    {
        public _SID_AND_ATTRIBUTES User;
    }


    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct _SID_AND_ATTRIBUTES
    {
        public IntPtr Sid;
        public int Attributes;
    }

    [DllImport("advapi32")]
    static extern bool OpenProcessToken(
        IntPtr ProcessHandle, // handle to process
        int DesiredAccess, // desired access to process
        ref IntPtr TokenHandle // handle to open access token
    );

    [DllImport("kernel32")]
    static extern IntPtr GetCurrentProcess();

    [DllImport("advapi32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern bool GetTokenInformation(
        IntPtr hToken,
        TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS tokenInfoClass,
        IntPtr TokenInformation,
        int tokeInfoLength,
        ref int reqLength
    );

    [DllImport("kernel32")]
    static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

    [DllImport("advapi32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern bool ConvertSidToStringSid(
        IntPtr pSID,
        [In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] ref string pStringSid
    );

    [DllImport("advapi32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern bool ConvertStringSidToSid(
        [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] string pStringSid,
        ref IntPtr pSID
    );


    public static bool DumpUserInfo(IntPtr pToken, out IntPtr SID)
    {
        int Access = TOKEN_QUERY;
        IntPtr procToken = IntPtr.Zero;
        bool ret = false;
        SID = IntPtr.Zero;
        try
        {
            if (OpenProcessToken(pToken, Access, ref procToken))
            {
                ret = ProcessTokenToSid(procToken, out SID);
                CloseHandle(procToken);
            }
            return ret;
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private static bool ProcessTokenToSid(IntPtr token, out IntPtr SID)
    {
        TOKEN_USER tokUser;
        const int bufLength = 256;
        IntPtr tu = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(bufLength);
        bool ret = false;
        SID = IntPtr.Zero;
        try
        {
            int cb = bufLength;
            ret = GetTokenInformation(token, TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS.TokenUser, tu, cb, ref cb);
            if (ret)
            {
                tokUser = (TOKEN_USER)Marshal.PtrToStructure(tu, typeof(TOKEN_USER));
                SID = tokUser.User.Sid;
            }
            return ret;
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(tu);
        }
    }

    public static string ExGetProcessInfoByPID(int PID, out string SID)//, out string OwnerSID)
    {
        IntPtr _SID = IntPtr.Zero;
        SID = String.Empty;
        try
        {
            Process process = Process.GetProcessById(PID);
            if (DumpUserInfo(process.Handle, out _SID))
            {
                ConvertSidToStringSid(_SID, ref SID);
            }
            return process.ProcessName;
        }
        catch
        {
            return "Unknown";
        }
    }
```